# VBA Script transform formula to value while copying to another workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I'm currently trying to write a VB script for the first time and i'm struggling with this new language. 
I need to copy multiple worksheet to a a new workbook and replace formulas by the calculated values.

I succeded on copying 2 worksheet in a new workbook but I don't understand how to use my own submethod to transform formula into values.

This is the code i have so far :

```
Sub myMacro()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Add
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SHEET_1").Copy Before:=wb.Sheets(1)
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SHEET_2").Copy Before:=wb.Sheets(1)
    wb.SaveAs "newWB.xlsx"
End Sub
```

All i need now is, during the copy, transform formula with values.
Thanks

Comment: Just set the values of the cells to the values calculated by the formulas e.g. `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SHEET_1").Range("A1:Z1000").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SHEET_1").Range("A1:Z1000").Value` - obviously change `Range("A1:Z1000")` as required.

Comment: That works but i don't want to change my formula into my source workbook but only in my destination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following on from my comment, try this:

```
Sub myMacro()
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Add
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SHEET_1").Copy Before:=wb.Sheets(1)
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SHEET_2").Copy Before:=wb.Sheets(1)
    wb.Sheets("SHEET_1").Range("A1:Z1000").Value = wb.Sheets("SHEET_1").Range("A1:Z1000").Value 
    wb.Sheets("SHEET_2").Range("A1:Z1000").Value = wb.Sheets("SHEET_2").Range("A1:Z1000").Value
wb.SaveAs "newWB.xlsx"
End Sub
```

The above code changes the new worksheets' formulas to values in the range A1:Z1000 (in the new destination workbook).

Comment: That works but i don't want to change my formula into my source workbook but only in my destination.

Comment: The original comment changed the source by using `Thisworkbook` however the code in the answer will change the destination sheets as they reference `wb` which is the new workbook

Comment: My bad, didn't see changes. Works perfectly thank you ! :)